# Transpose a dataframe and melt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataframe. There is always data available for each date and firm. But a given row isn't guaranteed to have the data; the row only has data if that firm is True.

```
    date        IBM       AAPL_total_amount    IBM_total_amount   AAPL_count_avg  IBM_count_avg 
    2013-01-31  True    False    29                9
    2013-01-31  True    True     29                9                 27               5
    2013-02-31  False   True                                         27               5
    2013-02-08  True    True     2                 3                  5                6
      ...
```

How could I transpose the above dataframe to long format?
Expected output:

```
     date        Firm     total_amount  count_avg
    2013-01-31   IBM         9              5   
    2013-01-31   AAPL        29             27
      ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might have to add some logic to drop all the boolean masks, but once you have that it's just a `stack`.

---

```
u = df.set_index('date').drop(['IBM', 'AAPL'], 1)
u.columns = u.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
u.stack(0)
```

---

```
                 count  total
date
2013-01-31 IBM     9.0   29.0
           AAPL    5.0   27.0
           IBM     9.0   29.0
2013-02-31 AAPL    5.0   27.0
2013-02-08 AAPL    6.0    5.0
           IBM     3.0    2.0
```

---

To drop all the masks if you don't have a list of keys, possibly use `select_dtypes`

```
df.select_dtypes(exclude=[bool])
```

Comment: Also if I have IBM_average_count, would this still work because of the splitting by underscore?

Comment: @arv you could specify to only split once to get that to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `wide_to_long` with pre-processing on `columns` and post-processing with slicing and `dropna`

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(col[::-1]) for col in df.columns.str.split('_')]
df_final = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['total','count'], 
                            i=['index','date'], 
                            j='firm', sep='_', suffix='\w+')[['total', 'count']]
              .reset_index(level=[1,2]).dropna())

Out[59]:
             date  firm  total  count
index
0      2013-01-31   IBM   29.0    9.0
1      2013-01-31   IBM   29.0    9.0
1      2013-01-31  AAPL   27.0    5.0
2      2013-02-31  AAPL   27.0    5.0
3      2013-02-08   IBM    2.0    3.0
3      2013-02-08  AAPL    5.0    6.0
```

Comment: Is there  a way to do this more generally? With more variables (other than total and count) like monthy_count, yearly_count too

Comment: @arv: if you mean columns in these format: `IBM_total,  IBM_count,  AAPL_total, AAPL_count, IBM_monthly_count, IBM_yearly_count, AAPL_monthly_count, AAPL_year_count,...`, it would work with minor modification of codes. Please update your question to reflect these new columns and new desired output.

Comment: @arv: specify `n=1` in `split`, change `stubnames=['total','count']` to `stubnames=['total_amount','count_avg']` and change slicing `[['total', 'count']]` to `[['total_amount',  'count_avg']]`

Answer (score 0):

That's an unusual table design. Let's assume the table is called `df`.

So you first want to find the list of tickers:

Either you have them elsewhere:

```
tickers = ['AAPL','IBM']
```

or you can extract them from your table:

```
tickers = [c for c in df.columns 
    if not c.endswith('_count') and 
    not c.endswith('_total') and 
    c != 'date']
```

Now you have to loop over the tickers:

```
res = []
for tic in tickers:
    sub = df[df[tic]][ ['date', f'{tic}_total','f{tic}_count'] ].copy()
    sub.columns = ['date', 'Total','Count']
    sub['Firm'] = tic
    res.append(sub)

res = pd.concat(res, axis=0)
```

Eventually, you might want to reorder the columns:

```
res = res[['date','Item','Total','Count']]
```

You might want to handle duplicates. From what I read in your example, you want to drop them:

```
res = res.drop_duplicates()
```